# Constructing Child Objects in PHP

Tags: php, oop

I have an abstract parent class `Item`, from which different types of items extend: `ItemTypeA`, `ItemTypeB`, and `ItemTypeC`. From my database result, I have an array:

```
array(

'item_name' => 'This is the item name',
'item_type' => 'ItemTypeA'

);
```

In PHP, what's the best way to create the item? Should I do something similar to the following?

```
static function constructFromDatabase($result){

$type = $result['item_type'];
$item = new $type;
return $item;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `$item = new $type;` should work just fine, [source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php#89296)

Answer (score 0):

You can even do `return new $result['item_type'];`, for performance -and maybe clarity/simplicity- reasons, if you are not going to use the intermediate variables anywhere else.